# check ping (in Milliseconds) with php and compare

Tags: php, compare, ping

what i need is a script (obviously in PHP) that pings a server, and returns its ping in MS, then it compares it, so lets say if the ping is higher then 5000MS it'll display something like "Quite slow", or etc...
something like

```
if($ms > 5000){return "Quite slow...";}
```

so thank you for your time reading this and a special thank to whoever will make that script!

Comment: What did you tried? Did you looked at `shell_exec` and similar?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is straightforward request for somebody to write code for the OP

Comment: No i only tried fSockOpen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is accurate, but here's my try.

**PHP:**

```
function microtime_float() {
    list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);
}

$start = microtime_float();
$fp = fsockopen('www.google.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
$end = microtime_float();
$ms = ($end - $start) * 1000;

echo sprintf('Ping: %sms', $ms);
```

micrtime_float() from http://php.net/manual/de/function.microtime.php :-)

Comment: If you used `microtime(true)` you could eliminate the need for microtime_float()